# Стилизация и добавление информации в теги select->option

Tags: css3, html5, sass

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить иконки цвета в выпадающие списки. У меня была пара вариантов с использованием тега span, с использованием картинки, но пока неудачно. Примеры моего кода все в скриншотах, скрин макета тоже
[image: часть макета, где нужно добавить иконку цвета]
[image: как сейчас выглядит у меня эта часть]
[image: пример с использованием картинки]
[image: пример с тегом span, html]
[image: пример с тегом span, sass]

Саму картинку стилизовать не пришлось, потому что она как раз 12 на 12, что мне и нужно было. Так что пример с картинкой чуть проще